# Wireless connection problem (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I cannot turn on wireless connection. 
I used wireless script to collect the information [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10001735/).
How I can get it works?

Answer (score 1):

It shows wifi as hardblocked, disabled by hardware switch, if there isn't a switch you may need to `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and `sudo rfkill unblock all` for wifi to work

Look for a switch first, check owners manual